# How to handle object list by using placeholder in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have an object namely, Counter

```
public class Counter{
    private String counterGroup;
    private String counterName;
    private String counterValue;

    //getters & setters
}

public class Task{
    private String taskName;
    private List<Counter> counters;

    //getters & setters
}
```

In my spring.xml

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/test.properties"/>
<bean id="task" class="com.test.Task">
        <property name="taskName" value="${task.name}"/>
        <property name="counters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="counter1"/>
            <ref bean="counter2"/>
        </list>

</bean>

<bean id="counter1" class="com.test.Counter">
      <property name="counterGroup" value=${counter.group1}/>
      <property name="counterName" value=${counter.name1}/>
      <property name="counterValue" value=${counter.value1}/>
</bean>

<bean id="counter2" class="com.test.Counter">
      <property name="counterGroup" value=${counter.group2}/>
      <property name="counterName" value=${counter.name2}/>
      <property name="counterValue" value=${counter.value2}/>
</bean>
```

In the test.properties

```
task.name=task1
counter.group1=g1
counter.name1=n1
counter.value1=v1
counter.group2=g2
counter.name2=n2
counter.value2=v2
```

If I have more number of counters then I have to edit both the properties as well as the spring.xml file. As I'm new to Spring and Java, I don't believe this is the right approach to solve this issue.

Can anybody suggest a different approach to solve the same issue.

Comment: AFAIK, this is the approach to use. If you need to set different values for the properties of the Counter class you will need to create 2 instances of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that is probably approach to use. However you may make your application looks better, if you use factory methods and object builders. For example:

```
public class Counter {
    .......
    public static Counter createFor(String descriptor){
        String[] params = descriptor.split(":");
        return new Counter(params[0], params[1], params[2]);
    } 
}
```

your context:

```
<bean id="task" class="com.test.Task">
        <property name="taskName" value="${task.name}"/>
        <property name="counters">
        <list>
            <bean class="com.test.Counter" factoryMethod="createFor">
                 <constructor-arg ref="${counter.descriptor1}"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="com.test.Counter" factoryMethod="createFor">
                 <constructor-arg ref="${counter.descriptor2}"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
</bean>
```

In the test.properties

```
task.name=task1
counter.descriptor1=g1:n1:v1
counter.descriptor2=g2:n2:v2
```

Of course you're not limited by this and may upgrade or apply any similar design techniques.

Comment: so the main approach in comparison with original solution is getting rid of copy-paste snippets of the application